# Array forEach skips odd indices

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Needing to remove some classes on elements that are prefixed with `nf-` and retain all others. Elements may have one or more classes with the prefix mentioned.

```
<div class="custom-nf">
  <div class="input nf-input-outer nf-validation">
    <div class="nf-container">
      <div class="nf-outer nf-outer-input nf-outer-validation">
        <div class="nf-middle">
          <div class="nf-inner">
            <label for="dummy" class="nf-label"></label>
            <input id="dummy" type="text" class="nf-input"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have the script below which gets all elements with the class prefix of `nf-` then for each element look over the classList property and for each class decide if the current class string matches the prefix as defined in the regex. If true, remove the class from the element.

```
(function(){
  // get elements with nf- prefix class
  var nfClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-nf [class*="nf-"]');
  // each element found
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(nfClasses, function(element){
    // each class per element with classList
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(element.classList, function(el){
      // only for classes that match prefix nf-
      if (el == el.match(/^nf-.*/g)) {
        // remove nf- class from the element
        element.classList.remove(el);
      }
    });
  });
})();
```

Now the code appears to run fine and remove classes with the prefix but the inner forEach part doesn't remove classes that appear as odd indexes within the classList array. Here is what the HTML looks like after the code has run:

```
<div class="custom-nf">
  <div class="input nf-validation">
    <div class="">
      <div class="nf-outer-input">
        <div class="">
          <div class="">
            <label for="dummy" class=""></label>
            <input id="dummy" type="text" class=""></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Running the code will reduce the remaining classes, and so on until all are gone but this isn't practical and there is an unknown how many classes an element may have with the prefix.

I have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chickensoup64/fcu1ypds/) up and running for this if you want to take a look.

Why is the inner forEach skipping odd indices and how do I correct it?

Comment: I am not sure, so I won't make this an answer, but I'd guess that modifying the `element.classList` from inside the callback would change the pointer, hence skipping the element next to the one just removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying the `element.classList` from inside the callback changes the indexing of the array, hence skipping the element next to the one just removed.

Just change the outer callback:

```
(function() {
  // get elements with nf- prefix class
  var nfClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-nf [class*="nf-"]');
  // each element found
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(nfClasses, function(element) {
    // here you gather class names to remove
    var toRemove = [];

    // each class per element with classList
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(element.classList, function(el) {
      // only for classes that match prefix nf-
      if (el.match(/^nf-.*/)) {
        // remove nf- class from the element
        toRemove.push(el);
      }
    });

    // now actually remove those classes
    toRemove.forEach(function(el) {
      element.classList.remove(el);
    });
  });
})();
```

see it in action at https://jsfiddle.net/fcu1ypds/5/

Comment: Makes perfect sense that the array is shorter after each remove, seems obvious now you point it out. Guess I assumed the array length wouldn't be impacted until after the forEach loop had completed per array; somewhat storing the index until all loops were finished. Much appreciated. Thanks heaps.